# How to add legend to multiple historam in basic R?

Tags: r, graphics

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-plot-multiple-histograms-in-r/

The above page shows how to plot multiple histograms in the same plot using basic R. But no legend is shown on the figure. How to add a legend to annotate the source of each histogram in basic R?

Answer (score 1):

You can add legend() and specify the content. With the sample data from your cited homepage:

```
# create data vector
x1 = rnorm(1000, mean=60, sd=10)
x2 = rnorm(1000, mean=0, sd=10)
x3 = rnorm(1000, mean=30, sd=10)

# create multiple histogram
hist(x1, col='red', xlim=c(-35, 100))
hist(x2, col='green', add=TRUE)
hist(x3, col='blue', add=TRUE)

# create legend
legend("topright", c("x1", "x2", "x3"), col=c("red", "green", "blue"), lwd=10)
```

[image]